# Django not running on heroku

Tags: django, heroku

Followed the "Getting started with Django on heroku/ceadar" guide to the letter and FINALLY managed to sort out some issues on app deployment

```
Successfully installed django psycopg2
 Cleaning up...
 Discovering process types
 Procfile declares types -> (none)
 Compiled slug size is 8.0MB
 Launching... done, v4
 http://<watever>.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
```

and the guide says the webserver should be up. but heroku ps shows no processes, and obviously the page doesnt load.

tail of the heroku log:

```
2012-01-19T10:28:29+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to down
2012-01-19T10:28:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to created
2012-01-19T10:28:32+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-01-19T10:30:32+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H99 (Platform error) -> GET <watever>
.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=


(venv) C:\Python27\facebook\venv\myapp>heroku ps
Process  State  Command
-------  -----  -------
```

should I be starting the webserver explicitly? wat am I doing wrong?

Comment: have u declared a web process in your proc file? for example: web: gunicorn_django -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 9 -k gevent --max-requests 250 --preload settings

Answer (score 9):

The Procfile I use for my django/heroku instance looks like this:

```
web: python hellodjango/manage.py runserver "0.0.0.0:$PORT"
```

As has been mentioned, if you have no Procfile and you're using the default webserver, it will essentially do the above - but try being explicit.  You can try running it from the heroku console instead, to see what (if any) errors it gets:

```
heroku run python hellodjango/manage.py runserver
```

Comment: The Procfile was not needed. Heroku automatically detects a django app starts it for the default development server.

Comment: As I said... if you have no Procfile and you're using the default web server, it will essentially do the above.  But since you were having trouble I was suggesting you do it explicitly.

Comment: What is the default server? Is there anything wrong with using it?

Comment: @MikeVella you can't use it in production as it's not even multithreaded. [This guy](http://blog.etianen.com/blog/2014/01/19/gunicorn-heroku-django/) says to use Waitress.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same problem, although I don't know if it was for the same reason or not.

While executing this command from the tutorial:

django-admin.py startproject hellodjango .

I changed the name of the app to something else (not just in this command, of course), but I omitted the '.' at the end. This caused the script to create an app inside a directory of the same name rather right in the directory I was in and that caused Heroku's server-side script to fail to detect the app as a Django app.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem as well.  Make sure your Procfile looks correct by running...

```
$heroku run bash
```

to open a terminal with access to heroku.  And then...

```
$cat Procfile
```

This will show you what is actually in your Procfile.  The first line (in my local file) in mine wasn't being read for some reason.  Then, I had a "}" appended to my file.  I was creating my file in TextEdit on a Mac - should have been using SublimeText or another text editor.  You can also call

```
$echo "web: gunicorn hello:app" >> Procfile
```

Or whatever you want your Procfile to say.  This will change your Procfile to whatever you echo.

Comment: This change Procfile but application is deployed by default from master branch where this changes don't apply. Run: heroku logs and there can be found Procfile config used.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with Django on Heroku for some time and decided to put together a very opinionated but functioning bootstrap. I hope it can help others along the road: https://github.com/callmephilip/django-heroku-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

The key is here:

```
Procfile declares types -> (none)
```

Heroku doesn't know how to run your application.  I assume `python hellodjango/manage.py runserver` works locally for you?  If so, Heroku should be able to pick this up.

Also check that you have a `requirements.txt` in the repo root, and a `settings.py` in one of your project subdirectories.

Comment: The runserver works fine locally. and the requirements.txt is present and settings.py too. The ProcFile is in the repo root and has the line: web: python madfb/manage.py runserver

Comment: The first time I pushed to heroku I didn't have a `Procfile` and It wordked just fine. I added the `Procfile` after installing `gunicorn`. Also, keep in mind that cedar is still in beta

Comment: Cedar is beta technically, but far from the state in which it is unstable.  A Procfile isn't required if you have a 'standard' setup such as Rails or Flask, Play! etc

Comment: I raised a ticket and heroku replied. looked like the django app directory was not checked in even though GIT said that the changes were pushed. I had sent them the check-in logs too. Now i did the whole thing from scratch, used a pre-compiled psycog2 and it works. The Procfile was not needed. Heroku automatically detects a django app starts it.