# Issues Running Heroku Django Tutorial

Tags: python, django, heroku, foreman

I've been following the steps in the Heroku-Django tutorial (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) to get a proof-of-concept version of a Django app running on Heroku and so far am getting stuck at the deployment step.  I'm working on OS X 10.8, if it matters.  I've followed all the instructions to the letter, but when I get to the deployment step I end up with the following error:

```
-----> Discovering process types

 !     Heroku push rejected due to an unrecognized error.
 !     We've been notified, see http://support.heroku.com if the problem persists.


To git@heroku.com:stormy-earth-5394.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:stormy-earth-5394.git'
```

I've reported the error to support.heroku.com yesterday but have not received any response yet.  https://status.heroku.com/ indicates no current issues.

Here's the directory structure for the app:

```
hellodjango/
    Procfile
    hellodjango/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    manage.py
    requirements.txt
    venv/
```

Running

```
python manage.py runserver
```

works correctly and I can browse to the expected default page.

Here's the full output of the deployment step.

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 3.92 KiB, done.
Total 13 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Python app detected
-----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.3.
-----> Preparing Python runtime (python-2.7.3)
-----> Installing Distribute (0.6.34)
-----> Installing Pip (1.2.1)
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.2.1)
       Downloading/unpacking Django==1.4.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
         Running setup.py egg_info for package Django

       Downloading/unpacking distribute==0.6.31 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
         Running setup.py egg_info for package distribute

       Downloading/unpacking dj-database-url==0.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
         Downloading dj-database-url-0.2.1.tar.gz
         Running setup.py egg_info for package dj-database-url

       Downloading/unpacking psycopg2==2.4.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
         Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2

           no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/src/_build'
       Installing collected packages: Django, distribute, dj-database-url, psycopg2
         Running setup.py install for Django
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/django-admin.py from 600 to 755

           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/django-admin.py to 755
         Found existing installation: distribute 0.6.34
           Uninstalling distribute:
             Successfully uninstalled distribute
         Running setup.py install for distribute
           Before install bootstrap.
           Scanning installed packages
           Setuptools installation detected at /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages
           Non-egg installation
           Moving elements out of the way...
           Already patched.
           /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info already patched.

           Installing easy_install script to /app/.heroku/python/bin
           Installing easy_install-2.7 script to /app/.heroku/python/bin
           After install bootstrap.
           /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info already exists
         Running setup.py install for dj-database-url

         Running setup.py install for psycopg2
           building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/green.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/pqpath.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/utils.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/utils.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/connection_int.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_int.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/connection_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/cursor_int.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/cursor_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/lobject_int.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/lobject_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/notify_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/notify_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/xid_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/adapter_binary.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/adapter_datetime.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/adapter_list.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/adapter_pboolean.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/adapter_pint.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/adapter_qstring.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/microprotocols.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/typecast.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
           gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/lib -lpq -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.so

           no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/src/_build'
       Successfully installed Django distribute dj-database-url psycopg2
       Cleaning up...
-----> Collecting static files
       0 static files copied.

-----> Discovering process types

 !     Heroku push rejected due to an unrecognized error.
 !     We've been notified, see http://support.heroku.com if the problem persists.


To git@heroku.com:stormy-earth-5394.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:stormy-earth-5394.git'
```

I suspect that the heroku might be related to the fact that foreman check outputs the following error, but I have no idea why foreman doesn't think there's any processes defined in Procfile when I have the exact line I'm supposed to from the tutorial.

```
$ foreman check
ERROR: no processes defined
$ cat Procfile 
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload
```

Any pointers on where to check next would be appreciated.  I worked on a different Django Heroku app several months ago but didn't run into these issues then.

Output of heroku logs is also less than helpful.

```
2013-02-07T00:15:50+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-02-07T00:17:31+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation failed: unrecognized error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your Procfile is ASCII Text:

```
file *
```

I think some people were having issues with unicode:
[Problems getting my sinatra based app to work on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440389/problems-getting-my-sinatra-based-app-to-work-on-heroku)

Also, perhaps you already have an existing Heroku project called "stormy-earth-5394" and it is trying to sync the git repo.  It might be worth deleting the dummy project and creating a new Heroku project:

```
heroku destroy --app stormy-earth-5394
heroku create
```

And then re-trying:

```
git push heroku master
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Comment: ASCII was the issue.  Had my vimrc setup to automatically encode things as unicode (which is supposed to be a "good thing").  Thanks!

Comment: At some point I may try to go through the foreman code that does the validation and update it now that Ruby 1.9 supports other character encodings.  Can't believe this was the issue...

Answer (score 2):

I have found that 'heroku logs' usually works well to debug these issues.

I think we should try it with gunicorn. I tried it on my local machine and it worked ok, and then deployed to a sample app and it works fine (http://arcane-shore-6254.herokuapp.com).

**Step 1**: Add 'gunicorn' to your requirements.txt

**Step 2**: Within your Procfile, change your 'web' process to:

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi:application
```

**Step 3**: Commit and Redeploy. See if that works :)

Comment: Furthermore, check that the Procfile is in the root of your repository. I assume it would be, seeing as Heroku has installed your Python requirements correctly.

Comment: This is all that's in heroku logs - it was one of the first places I looked.

2013-02-07T00:15:50+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-02-07T00:17:31+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation failed: unrecognized error

I'll try gunicorn and see what happens.

Comment: Also, Procfile is in the root of the repo - I posted the directory structure above.

Comment: Tried the suggestion above to use gunicorn and get exactly the same error (both in the output from the deploy and the heroku logs output).

Comment: Can you do me a favour and please add the output from the commands **foreman version** and **heroku version**

Comment: $ foreman version
0.60.0

$ heroku version
heroku-toolbelt/2.35.0 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3

Answer (score -1):

You might want to take a look at the responses to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924841/django-not-running-on-heroku).

In particular, you should probably think about whether you're in the right directory or whether `manage.py` should be invoked with hellodjango in the path.